# how to implement two fingers panning like safari broswer?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.2, panning

i try to implement panning and zooming functionality like safari browser in ipad.

i used UIPinchGestureRecognizer for zooming with two fingers touch. but i dont know how to implement two fingers panning.

when i touch with two fingers its tap count is 1.

please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want the tapCount, you want the number of touches. If you touch down with two fingers you can two touch events each with a tap count of 1.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

[touches count] would return 2, one for each finger tip.

[Read through the apple guide for touch events](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1)

Comment: for single finger touch i have to do other action and if user touch with two finger i have to panning of view

Comment: can you please describe in detail

Comment: do you understand the difference between tapCount and the number of touches?

Comment: - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint thePoint;
 NSLog(@"%d",[touches count]);
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 CGPoint thePoint;
 NSLog(@"%d",[touches count]);
}
but both method log 1 count